# I need some explain on Rx behavior

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

When I use Reactive Extensions (Rx) with linq filter what happen under the hood?

Is this,

```
var move = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(frm, "MouseMove");
IObservable<System.Drawing.Point> points = from evt in move
                                           select evt.EventArgs.Location;
var overfirstbisector = from pos in points
                        where pos.X == pos.Y 
                        select pos;
var movesub = overfirstbisector.Subscribe(pos => Console.WriteLine("mouse at " + pos));
```

more efficient from this?

```
private void MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Location.X == args.LocationY)
    Console.WriteLine("mouse at " + args.Location);
}
```

I dont talk about the filtering logic itself but about the events behavior of the methods.
In Rx do the event raised exactly the same way of the regular event but with warapper or there is somthing special under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there's no algorithmic performance benefit for using the Rx query over the typical event handler - in fact, your Rx query may actually be marginally slower than the typical event handler. "Under the hood" the Rx query is basically doing the same thing as the typical event handler, but in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

The Rx query is not more efficient than the directly subscribing the events. Under the hood, the Rx query is still subscribing to the events and adding a bit of logic (e.g. for the schedulers), so I would say you are trading a bit of performance for increased readability, flexibility (since you can quickly change and adapt the query) and testability (since the Rx query can be much more easily unit-tested).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "special" about Rx. Rx is just a library, not a language feature. If you wanted to, you could have built Rx yourself in a normal old C# project, it just happened that the smart people at Microsoft thought of it first. The code is open source now so you can just download it and see how it all works (admittedly it got a lot more complex in v2)

In your example, the Rx code will need to do the following:

1. Reflectively look for an event called "MouseMove" on the `frm` object
2. Create an observable sequence (`IObservable<MouseEventArgs>`) from the event
3. Ensure the safe semantics of the implicit IObservable contract e.g. that values are sequential, the subscriptions are thread safe etc..
4. Do the condition check
5. Subscribe to the sequence (safely)
6. Print to the console when a value is pushed.

In contrast, the non-rx code does the following:

1. Recieves a virtual call from a base class
2. does the condition check
3. Prints the value to the console.

So no reflection & no safety checks, but the same result. In practice the performance will be very fast for both so you are unlikely to see any performance difference.

With regards to Unit testing, I think any argument for or against is nonsense. We are talking about a MouseMove event, how are you going to unit test that? Putting all that Rx in your code base doesn't appear to pay for itself in my opinion (slower, more code, another framework for a dev to understand, etc...)